# Error imprimiendo valor de variable a través de un condicional

Tags: visual-studio

Que estoy haciendo mal, supuestamente al ingresar el "a" me debe salir el mensaje "Es una vocal"

```
Dim letra As String 
if letra = "a" Then 

MsgBox("Es una vocal")

Else
MsgBox("Es una consonante")
End If
```

Comment: Muy buenas Diego, ¿donde estas dándole el valor a la variable `letra`?

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/576272524015566858/576272700369141770/41ecca614ddce9f402f95ef509a89971.png?width=424&height=427

Comment: En el código no le das ningún valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No has asignado valor alguno a la variable `a` es decir la declaras pero no contiene que valor alguno asignado por ejemplo `letra = "a"` para que al hacer la comparación encuentre la coincidencia.

Entonces solo deberías hacer esto

```
Dim letra As String 
letra = "a"
```

Posterior ya puedes hacer la comparación y te debe devolver lo que contiene tu `if` en la primer parte que es el mensaje de **es una vocal**

Completo se debería ver de este modo

```
Dim letra As String 
letra = "a"

if letra = "a" Then 

MsgBox("Es una vocal")

Else
MsgBox("Es una consonante")
End If
```